# Laravel - Lucene Search

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, lucene, composer-php

Might be very specific to the package this. Or hopefully someone can help.

I am using this Composer Package - https://github.com/nqxcode/laravel-lucene-search

I have followed the install instructions (I feel)...

I have set the config up as follows :

```
'index' => [

        'path' => storage_path() . '/lucene-search/index',

        'models' => [
            // Add models descriptions here.
            'Pack' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'pack_title','pack_description',
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

Inside my "Pack" model. I have the following...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Nqxcode\LuceneSearch\Model\Searchable;

class Pack extends Model implements Searchable {

    public function isSearchable()
    {
        return $this->publish;
    }

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        'pack_title' => 'required',
        'pack_description' => 'required',
        'primary_category_id' => 'required',
        'keystage'  => 'required',
        'pack_unit_price' => 'required'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = "pack_id";

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    //protected $fillable = [];

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

I have then created a "SearchesController"

It looks like this...

```
<?php

class SearchesController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * GET /search
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $query = Search::query('A New Pack Title'); // search by 'name' field.

        $models = $query->get();

        var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());

        $count = $query->count();
    }
```

My var_dump shows this...

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(56) "select * from `categories` order by `category_order` asc" ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } ["time"]=> float(1.26) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(90) "select * from `packs` where `packs`.`deleted_at` is null and `packs`.`pack_id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["time"]=> float(0.59) } }
```

It just feels like it is not doing a search within the Packs model. Or a non significant one.

Am I doing something glaringly wrong. Hopefully one of you guys can help

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When config is set up, you must run `php artisan search:rebuild -v` for initialization of a search index.

After that it is already possible to carry out search queries.
If the index isn't initialized, the result of any search query will be empty.

Comment: Hi Andrey @nqxcode I've ran a search:rebuild and had no such luck with that either. I've created items in my DB etc. But it just doesn't seem to work. Interestingly that command you mentioned is not in your docs. Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I not absolutely understand a problem essence. You have problems with creation of an index? or what else?

You have to update an search index after each creation or updating of the indexed models.

You can carry out full or partial updating of an index.

For **full updating** use command `php artisan search:rebuild` (look "Usage->Artisan commands" section in readme).

**Partial updating** of search index will work after registration of the necessary events (look "Partial updating of search index" section in readme).